# Why does elem.innerHTML not work here?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my script.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // this function runs when the DOM is ready, i.e. when the document has been parsed
  var elem = document.getElementById("output");
  elem.innerHTML = 123;
});
```

```html
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<div id="output">11</div>
```

When I load index.html in the browser, I don't see a 123 displayed. Why so ?

#### Original HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div id="output">11</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in the snippet, so not reproduceable

Comment: I hit "Run code snippet" on StackOverflow and I see "123"

Comment: You did have a script, is there something in the script that is breaking it?

Comment: `<head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>` This is what I have. No working in my browser.

Comment: Try removing `async`, there's no reason that should be there.

Comment: Your code its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your post revision history, you previously had `<script async type="text/javascript" src="script.js">`

`async` instructs the browser that it can run independently. This means it can also run *after* `DOMContentLoaded` has fired. Removed `async`and the event will reliably fire.

[Async-loaded scripts with DOMContentLoaded or load event handlers not being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237044/async-loaded-scripts-with-domcontentloaded-or-load-event-handlers-not-being-call)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I changed to "defer" and it started working fine. "async" means downloaded while first render is happening and execute as soon as download is complete. "defer" means download while first render is happening and execute after first render is complete. My script was executing soon after download which was before the first render was complete. Correct ?

Comment: Correct. To simplify: `defer` is still blocked by the HTML parser. `async` doesn't care and is independent.